# Groovy sorting of nodes provides incorrect result

Tags: sorting, groovy

I am trying to sort an xml file in groovy, but when looking at the result it is not sorted like I expected (alphabetical sorted).

Here is the code

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder;
import groovy.util.OrderBy;
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil;


String xmlString = "<root>";
xmlString = xmlString + "<record><item>CBCP3030cmackham************00000036</item><field>CBCP</field></record>";
xmlString = xmlString + "<record><item>CBCP3030cmackham************00000036</item><field>CBCP</field></record>";
xmlString = xmlString + "<record><item>CASHser@mdgrathnicol.co*302000000143</item><field>CASH</field></record>";
xmlString = xmlString + "<record><item>CASH2001724*************302000000143</item><field>CASH</field></record>";
xmlString = xmlString + "</root>";

def rootsFTPData = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlString);
rootsFTPData.children().sort(true) {
  [it.item.text()]
};

def xmlStringTemp = XmlUtil.serialize(rootsFTPData);
println xmlStringTemp;
```

and this is the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
  <record>
    <item>CASH2001724*************302000000143</item>
    <field>CASH</field>
  </record>
  <record>
    <item>CBCP3030cmackham************00000036</item>
    <field>CBCP</field>
  </record>
  <record>
    <item>CBCP3030cmackham************00000036</item>
    <field>CBCP</field>
  </record>
  <record>
    <item>CASHser@mdgrathnicol.co*302000000143</item>
    <field>CASH</field>
  </record>
</root>
```

I would have expected

```
CASH2001724*************302000000143
CASHser@mdgrathnicol.co*302000000143
CBCP3030cmackham************00000036
CBCP3030cmackham************00000036
```

is there something wrong with my code or how can I achieve the correct sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning an array with a single item, the text in it.

Return just the text:

```
rootsFTPData.children().sort(true) { it.item.text() }
```

What you're doing now is this:

```
rootsFTPData.children().sort(true) { [it.item.text()] }
```

That puts the text inside an array (the array contains a single element, the text), so Groovy will sort it however it sorts on an array. You want to sort on text, so return text. Not an array.

Unrelated, but there's no need for string concatenation like that in Groovy:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

String xmlString = """
<root>
  <record><item>CBCP3030cmackham************00000036</item><field>CBCP</field></record>
  <record><item>CBCP3030cmackham************00000036</item><field>CBCP</field></record>
  <record><item>CASHser@mdgrathnicol.co*302000000143</item><field>CASH</field></record>
  <record><item>CASH2001724*************302000000143</item><field>CASH</field></record>
</root>
"""

def rootsFTPData = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlString)
rootsFTPData.children().sort(true) { it.item.text() }

def xmlStringTemp = XmlUtil.serialize(rootsFTPData)
print xmlStringTemp
```

This produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <record>
    <item>CASH2001724*************302000000143</item>
    <field>CASH</field>
  </record>

  <record>
    <item>CASHser@mdgrathnicol.co*302000000143</item>
    <field>CASH</field>
  </record>

  <record>
    <item>CBCP3030cmackham************00000036</item>
    <field>CBCP</field>
  </record>

  <record>
    <item>CBCP3030cmackham************00000036</item>
    <field>CBCP</field>
  </record>    
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick feedback and yes you are correct, this sorts correctly. Unfortunately it does not solve my issue. The xml we have is more complex and build in a different function. I am relatively new to Groovy and try to understand why the example with the concatenation does not work?

Comment: @borntosucceed Because in your original code you return the `<item>` text in an array, so Groovy will "sort" it however it defaults to sorting arrays. If you want to sort on the `<item>` *text* then you need to return only the *text*, as in my example. The complexity of the XML is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks Dave, yes the [] brackets were the culprit.